# receiving only the filename in a shell command

Tags: shell, contextmenu, regedit

I want to get only the filename (and no the full path) when running a shell command on some file extension (In the context menu of it)
It is probably done somehow in the registry, in the file extension under HKCR. Any of %1 %l %L gives the full path. I want only the filename

thanks

---

The idea is good, but I can't make it work

I created the file- `GetFileName.bat`
I put it somewhere it is in the`%path%`

it looks like that:
`@set Ret="%~n1"`

and in the registry I put the following command

`cmd /k GetFileName "%L" & hh.exe -decompile extracted %Ret%`

which means:
* Run  this- GetFileName "%L"
* and then- hh.exe -decompile extracted %Ret%

but the `%Ret%` doesn't give me the result of the GetFileName, although it contains the environment variable Ret with the correct value.

I guess it doesn't allow in the registry to use this environment variable because it is in the same line

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%~n` modifier to extract a filename from a path in a script argument, but it does not appear to recognize other environment varaibles, so you'll have to stuff it into a separate batch file:

getext.bat:

```
@set Ret=%~n1
```

and then

```
C:\> getext hello.bat
C:\> echo %Ret%
hello
```